# Seting specifc ID/entity ID to categories

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a script that gets all categories on a csv file and starts creating them in DB (categoreis and subcategories...). I need to set specific IDs to the categories and subcategories, but currently I am having trouble to set the IDs.  When I try to set it, the categories and subcategories break.

Here is an example of my csv file structure:

> ID,ParentID,Name,top,columns,sort_order,Image,date_added,date_modified,language_id,seo_keyword,description,meta_description,meta_keywords,store_ids,layout,Status

```
355,2,Jewellery Boxes,,,,data/100-0-jewelleryboxes.jpg,,,,Jewellery Boxes,,,,,,TRUE
356,355,Leatherette Boxes,,,,data/106-100-leatheretteboxes.jpg,,,,Leatherette Boxes,,,,,,TRUE
```

My code:

```
require '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

function getCategories()
{
    $file = 'categorias-novo.csv';
    $arrResult = array();
    $headers = false;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if (empty($handle) === false) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if (!$headers) {
                $headers[] = $data;
            } else {
                $arrResult[] = $data;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $arrResult;
}

$ar = getCategories();



function importCategories($arrResult)
{

    //Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
    $parentId = '2';
    $list = array();
 $counter = 0;
    foreach ($arrResult as $import_category) {
        try {

            $enabled = 1;
           /* return var_dump($import_category[16]);
            if (strtolower($import_category[16]) == 'true') {
                $enabled = 1;
            } else {
                $enabled = 0;
            }*/
   $parentId = $import_category[1];
            if ($import_category[1] == 2) {
                $parentId = '2';
            }
            else {

                $parentId = $list[$import_category[1]];
            }



            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

            //return var_dump($import_category);


            $category->setId($categoryID);
           //$category->setId($import_category[0]);
           //  $category->setEntityId($desiredId);
            $category->setName($import_category[2]);
            $category->setMetaTitle($import_category[2]);
            $category->setIncludeInMenu(1);
            $category->setUrlKey($import_category[10]);
            $category->setDescription(strip_tags($import_category[11]));
            $category->setMetaDescription($import_category[12]);
            $category->setMetaKeywords($import_category[13]);
            $category->setIsActive($enabled);
            $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
            $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active anchor
            $category->setStoreId(0);


            $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);

            $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
            $category->setCustomUseParentSettings(true);
            $category->setImage($import_category[6]);





          $category->save();
            $list[$import_category[0]] = $category->getId();
            echo 'Category ' . $category->getName() . ' ' . $category->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Something failed for category ' . $import_category[2] . PHP_EOL;
            print_r($e);
        }
    }

    return $list;

}

importCategories($ar);
```

Can anyone tell me, what's wrong with my code ?